# java String remove spaces and add letter

Tags: java, android, string

If someone have idea how can i accomplish this.
Lets say i have one string:

```
String word = " adwq ijsdx djoaaiosj  czxc  f  wqeqw xcx  ";
```

I want to remove spaces and put before every word some another symbol or letter? So i can get something like this:

```
String newWord ="$adwq $ijsdx $djoaaiosj $czxc $f $wqeqw $xcx";
```

I tried something like this:

```
String newWord = word.replaceAll("\\s+"," ").replaceAll(" "," $");
```

and i get something like this :(

```
String newWord = $adwq $ijsdx $djoaaiosj $czxc $f $wqeqw $xcx $";
```

And how t detect if in string are multiple same words.

Comment: just insert a trim between your `replaceAll`. as for the duplicate words, split the string, then create a `Set` with those words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what I would do:

```
    newWord = newWord.trim(); // This would remove trailing and leading spaces
    String [] words = newWord.split("\\s+"); //split them on spaces
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for(int i=0;i<words.length-1;i++){
        sb.append('$');
        sb.append(words[i]);
        sb.append(' ');
    }
    if(words.length>0){
        sb.append('$');
        sb.append(words[words.length-1]);
    }
    newWord = sb.toString();
```

For your other question you can have a locale HashSet and check if each word has been already added there or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
// replace one or more spaces followed by a word boundary with space+dollar sign:
String newWord = word.replaceAll("\\s+\\b"," $").trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Trim the string first, and combine your `replaceAll` calls:

```
String word = " adwq ijsdx djoaaiosj  czxc  f  wqeqw xcx  ";
String newWord = word.trim().replaceAll("^\\b|\\s*(\\s)", "$1\\$");
System.out.println("'" + word + "'");
System.out.println("'" + newWord + "'");
```

*Output*

```
' adwq ijsdx djoaaiosj  czxc  f  wqeqw xcx  '
'$adwq $ijsdx $djoaaiosj $czxc $f $wqeqw $xcx'
```

*Explanation*

The `trim()` call will remove leading and trailing spaces:

```
"adwq ijsdx djoaaiosj  czxc  f  wqeqw xcx"
```

The regex contains two expressions separated by `|` (`or`). The second (`\\s*(\\s)`) will replace a sequence of spaces with the space (`$1`) and a dollar sign (`\\$`):

```
"adwq $ijsdx $djoaaiosj $czxc $f $wqeqw $xcx"
```

The first expression (`^\\b`) will replace a word boundary at the beginning of the string with a dollar sign (no space because `$1` is empty):

```
"$adwq $ijsdx $djoaaiosj $czxc $f $wqeqw $xcx"
```

This guards against the empty string, where `"    "` should become `""`.